# Samsung X4300 defaults to Letter instead of A4

Tags: printing, printer

I'm using a Samsung X4300 MultiXpress, using the Samsung Universal Print Driver. The issue is that the printer defaults to Letter instead of A4; I've edited the Normal setting in the Printing Preferences setting, but it never sticks- once I try to print something, it always defaults back to Letter.

This is affecting a few machines on a small network.

We're running Windows 10 Professional 64 bit edition.

Comment: Are you using [this method](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c05588868)?

Answer (score 0):

> I've edited the Normal setting in the Printing Preferences

You need to set the defaults in Printing Defaults.

Go to Devices & Settings. Right-click the printer and select Printer Properties. Now click the Advanced tab and then the Printing Defaults button. The window that pops up looks like the Printing Preferences window. Set your paper size there and click OK. Now click the General button and the Printing Preferences tab, and check the settings; correct them here if necessary.

Those settings will now be the defaults.

However, what actually happens also depends on the application. For example, Word stores paper size in the document. Hence, if a document was saved with Letter as the default, that will not change if the default is changed. Neither will it change if you change the size at print time. Instead, you must change it from Page Setup. Note that Word will repaginate the document when you change the paper size.

Other apps can behave differently; for example, some apps have a setting for their own default paper size, independent of the printer.

Comment: That's what I meant by changing the preferences- apologies for not being clear.

It's also not an issue with the application- I've got Word set to always be in A4, but the printer still tries to override this.

Comment: If this is a shared printer, make sure you change Printing Defaults on the server. The setting on the printer itself (from its control panel) does not affect the printing from a PC/Mac. Make sure the sliders in the tray are firmly against the paper.

Comment: The server settings are correct for what I need. It still isn't working properly, unfortunately.

Comment: From the printer's control panel, check that the default paper size is A4, and then print a configuration page or other internal test page. Does that then use A4?